# How to get version id of a S3 object by ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have implemented aws-sdk library and can download and upload files successfully. I have enabled the versioning on S3. How could I get the version id of a S3 object by ruby? Could you show me a example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
bucket.objects[key].versions.latest
```

can return the latest version id of an object

reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

Answer (score 0):

you can get the version id from `Object`.

```
bucket.objects.map do |obj|
  "VERSION ID: #{obj.object.version_id}"
end
```

REF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#version_id-instance_method